C: Segmantation fault (core dumped)
While doing the CS50-task recover i finished everything and ran valgrind over it. Valgrind returns a possible segmentation fault, even though I made sure to never access memory, I don't have access to.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: ./recover [argument]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE* sdCard = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (sdCard == NULL) {
        printf("Couldn't open %s in read-mode", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    uint8_t buffer[512];

    // ###.png\0 => 8 characters
    char file_name[8];

    int fileNumber = 0;

    FILE* recoveredJPG;
    char* zeroes = NULL;

    int foundFirstJPEG = 0;

    // Create files
    while(fread(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), 512, sdCard)) {
        if (buffer[0] == 0xFF && buffer[1] == 0xD8 && buffer[2] == 0xFF && (buffer[3] & 0xFF) == 0xE0) {
            foundFirstJPEG = 1;

            if (fileNumber < 10) {
                zeroes = malloc(3*sizeof(char));

                if (zeroes == NULL) {
                    printf("Memory allocation failed!");
                    fclose(sdCard);
                    sdCard = NULL;
                    if (recoveredJPG != NULL) {
                        fclose(recoveredJPG);
                        recoveredJPG = NULL;
                    }
                    return 1;
                }

                strcpy(zeroes, "00");
            } else if (fileNumber >= 10) {
                zeroes = malloc(2*sizeof(char));

                if (zeroes == NULL) {
                    printf("Memory allocation failed!");
                    fclose(sdCard);
                    sdCard = NULL;
                    if (recoveredJPG != NULL) {
                        fclose(recoveredJPG);
                        recoveredJPG = NULL;
                    }
                    return 1;
                }

                strcpy(zeroes, "0");
            }

            if (zeroes == NULL) {
                printf("Memory allocation failed!");
                fclose(sdCard);
                sdCard = NULL;
                if (recoveredJPG != NULL) {
                    fclose(recoveredJPG);
                    recoveredJPG = NULL;
                }
                return 1;
            }

            sprintf(file_name, "%s%i.jpg", zeroes, fileNumber);
            if (recoveredJPG != NULL){
                fclose(recoveredJPG);
                recoveredJPG = NULL;
            }
            recoveredJPG = fopen(file_name, "w");
            if (recoveredJPG == NULL) {
                printf("Error while creating %s.", file_name);
                free(zeroes);
                zeroes = NULL;
                fclose(sdCard);
                sdCard = NULL;
                return 1;
            }
            free(zeroes);
            zeroes = NULL;
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), 512, recoveredJPG);
            fileNumber++;
        } else if (foundFirstJPEG) {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(uint8_t), 512, recoveredJPG);
        }
    }
    if (recoveredJPG != NULL) {
        fclose(recoveredJPG);
        recoveredJPG = NULL;
    }
    fclose(sdCard);
    sdCard = NULL;


    if (zeroes != NULL) {
        free(zeroes);
        zeroes = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}

I tried everything, NULLing every file after deleting, freeing every pointer before every return, making sure i check that every pointer isn't NULL before accessing. I still get a possible segmentation fault.
This is valgind's output:
==3125== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3125== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3125== Using Valgrind-3.22.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3125== Command: ./recover card.raw
==3125== 
==3125== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3125==    at 0x10948C: main (recover.c:81)
==3125==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==3125==    at 0x1091C4: main (recover.c:7)
==3125== 
==3125== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==3125==    at 0x4A0E294: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:48)
==3125==    by 0x10949D: main (recover.c:82)
==3125==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==3125==    at 0x1091C4: main (recover.c:7)
==3125== 
==3125== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==3125==    at 0x4A0E33C: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:51)
==3125==    by 0x10949D: main (recover.c:82)
==3125==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==3125==    at 0x1091C4: main (recover.c:7)
==3125== 
==3125== Invalid read of size 8
==3125==    at 0x4A0E353: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:51)
==3125==    by 0x10949D: main (recover.c:82)
==3125==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==3125== 
==3125== 
==3125== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==3125==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x8
==3125==    at 0x4A0E353: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:51)
==3125==    by 0x10949D: main (recover.c:82)
==3125==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==3125==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==3125==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==3125==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==3125==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==3125== 
==3125== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3125==     in use at exit: 4,571 bytes in 3 blocks
==3125==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 0 frees, 4,571 bytes allocated
==3125== 
==3125== 3 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 3
==3125==    at 0x4846828: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3125==    by 0x1092F2: main (recover.c:38)
==3125== 
==3125== 472 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 3
==3125==    at 0x4846828: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3125==    by 0x4A0EE6E: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==3125==    by 0x4A0EE6E: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:86)
==3125==    by 0x109210: main (recover.c:13)
==3125== 
==3125== 4,096 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 3
==3125==    at 0x4846828: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3125==    by 0x4A0E1A4: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
==3125==    by 0x4A1E513: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:347)
==3125==    by 0x4A1CF3B: _IO_file_xsgetn (fileops.c:1288)
==3125==    by 0x4A0F48A: fread (iofread.c:38)
==3125==    by 0x10927A: main (recover.c:33)
==3125== 
==3125== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3125==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3125==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3125==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3125==    still reachable: 4,571 bytes in 3 blocks
==3125==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3125== 
==3125== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==3125== ERROR SUMMARY: 4 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
/opt/cs50/bin/valgrind: line 13:  3125 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) /usr/bin/valgrind "$@"

PS: Please don't give any tips on how to solve the task recover.c from CS50 more efficiently, I will try doing that after i find out what causes this segmentation fault.
PPS: When running the file myself, i get no error and everything runs as normal.
Thanks for your help.

Maybe use gdb instead to try and figure out where exactly the segfault occurs?

Not necessarily causing your issue, but you should get rid of that zeroes thing. It is useless and complicates things. Read the manual for printf format specifiers. You need %03i to format that number with leading zeros.

yeah, I also tried completely getting rid of zeroes and still had the same error but I will sure look into printf again. thanks

==3125== Use of uninitialised value of size 8 ==3125==    at 0x4A0E33C: fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofclose.c:51)==3125==    by 0x10949D: main (recover.c:82) Look at line 82: fclose(recoveredJPG); Do you initialize recoveredJPG properly in any possible path where you could get to that line? Hint: Local variables are not automatically zero-initialized.

No, i did not initialize it. I figuered as it's a pointer it wouldn't be NULL when creating. I will try initializing it somehow and then running valgrind over it again.

"it wouldn't be NULL when creating" It may be NULL or not, as local variables are not initialized. As you only check for !=NULL you would treat any invalid random value as != NULL and try to close the file. Which will fail, of course.

But how will I initialize it though? I thought about trying to initalize it like this:
FILE* recoveredJPG = (FILE*)0x99; // 0x99 is just a random number

So you use != NULL to identify an invalid value in your own code. If the pointer holds anything else, you try to close that file. How do you get to any other value than NULL to initialize the pointer then? The pointer should never ever hold anything else than a value returned from fopen or NULL. Not some random integer value.

Alright, you're right, I was already getting dizzy from working on this project for so long, that's why I didn't think of NULLing it first but now it works. Thank you so much for your help.

Start with the first error. Fix that, then repeat.

Also run with the option to read var info and track origins (use the help option to find them).

suggest you run the code through cppcheck.

"Segmantation fault (core dumped)" isn't a helpful title since it basically means "bug". These could be caused by a number of things: pointer-related bugs, array out of bounds, incorrect use of standard lib functions, writing to read-only memory etc etc.

Well you've gotten as far as letting Valgrind chew through it, we just have to interpret the messages:

Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3125==    at 0x10948C: main (recover.c:81)

Yep, you are using recoveredJPG all over the place and not necessarily after calling fopen first. Since you check for NULL everywhere, this should be easy to fix by initializing the variable: FILE* recoveredJPG = NULL;.
Also, for readability reasons the program could do with some splitting up in smaller functions, instead of one big loop with multiple nested if statements.
